# PyCharm: Change color of text in Console based on output

Tags: pycharm

I created a special `print()` function that simulates how Logging works, but only in the Console. I'd like the color of the text output from these `Print()` statements to change based on the output.

**Here's an example of a few lines from the Console:**

> - 2021-12-24 14:49:07 | DEBUG | - Campaign "Test" budget is 250 / 0.
> - 2021-12-24 14:49:07 | DEBUG | - Getting sending data for campaign's 2 audiences...
> - 2021-12-24 14:49:07 | INFO  | - Randomly chose campaign "Test".
> - 2021-12-24 14:49:07 | INFO  | - Randomly chose audience "etest".
> - 2021-12-24 14:49:07 | WARN  | - Campaign is missing "Sending Timezone"
>   .

Is it possible to change each row's color in the Console based on the text?

For example, have lines with "WARN" appear in orange; etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) may help.

Example:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init()

def print_log(info, level):
    if(level == "WARN"):
        print(Fore.YELLOW + "[WARN] " + info)
        print(Style.RESET_ALL) # Don't forget to change back to normal

print_log("This is a warning", "WARN")
```

Actually, `Fore.YELLOW` send [ANSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to console, which can change the color of text in console.

Comment: If you replace the line `print(Fore.YELLOW + "[WARN] " + info)` with the line `print(Fore.YELLOW + "[WARN] " + info), end=""`, each time you run the function, the print would only take one line. Otherwise, it takes two lines because of the second print.